# forecast daily data for not near future

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, multiple-seasonalities

I am trying to get a forecast for the rest of 2017 based on 5 years of daily historical data. Im having issues with the weekly seasonality

I am trying to use the `auto.arima` function (with `xregs`).
my issue is that the weekly seasonality captured by the model is well captured in the near future forecast but decays as the forecast is far (after about 20 data points ahead).

here is the code for training:

```
premiums_ts_train <- ts(data = daily_data_train[, .(y)], frequency = 7, start = c(2013,1))
features_ts_train <- ts(data = daily_data_train[, .(feature1, feature2)], frequency = 7, start = c(2013, 1))

z <- fourier(ts(daily_data_train[, .(y)], frequency=365), K=5)
fit <- auto.arima(premiums_ts_train, xreg=cbind(z,features_ts_train), seasonal=FALSE)
```

And here is the output on the test:

[image: test set prediction vs actual]